# How to separate arrays in columns in python from json

Tags: python, json

I have this json array

['id: 123, name: Sara',
'id: 456, name: Jhon',
'id: 789, name: Paris'],

and i am using this code to seprate each part to be in addiferent column

```
for record in records:
  list1 = ['id: {0}, name: {1}'.format(sign['id'], sign['value']).record['sign']][0]
  list2 = ['id: {0}, name: {1}'.format(sign['id'], sign['value']).record['sign']][1]
  list3 = ['id: {0}, name: {1}'.format(sign['id'], sign['value']).record['sign']][2]
```

Comment: what is a json array? Do you mean a dictionary with a list as value or is a string?

Comment: yes it is a dic with list of strings

Comment: maybe with `dict(i.split(':') for i in 'id: 123, name: Sara'.split(','))` -> `{'id': ' 123', ' name': ' Sara'}`? [have to be strip... or add an extra ws to the cmds, `split(': ')`]